# Setting SGE for running an executable with different input files on different nodes

Tags: scripting, submission, sungridengine, slurm

I used to work with a cluster using SLURM scheduler, but now I am more or less forced to switch to a SGE-based cluster, and I'm trying to get a hang of it. The thing I was working on SLURM system involves running an executable using N input files, and set a SLURM configuration file in this fashion,

```
slurmConf.conf SLURM configuration file
    0   /path/to/exec /path/to/input1
    1   /path/to/exec /path/to/input2
    2   /path/to/exec /path/to/input3
    3   /path/to/exec /path/to/input4
    4   /path/to/exec /path/to/input5
    5   /path/to/exec /path/to/input6
    6   /path/to/exec /path/to/input7
    7   /path/to/exec /path/to/input8
    8   /path/to/exec /path/to/input9
    9   /path/to/exec /path/to/input10
```

And my working submission script in SLURM contains this line;

```
srun -n $SLURM_NNODES --multi-prog $slconf
$slconf refers to a path to that configuration file
```

This setup worked as I wanted - to run the executable with 10 different inputs at the same time with 10 nodes. Now that I just transitioned to SGE system, I want to do the same thing but I tried to read the manual and found nothing quite like SLURM. Could you please give me some light on how to achieve the same thing on SGE system?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If my or Dmitri's answer was useful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "job array" feature of the Grid Engine.

Create a shell script `sge_job.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# sge_job.sh -- SGE job description script
#
#$ -t 1-10
/path/to/exec /path/to/input$SGE_TASK_ID
```

And submit this script to SGE with `qsub`.

```
qsub sge_job.sh
```

Comment: Wow, this looks much cleaner than SLURM's approach! I will go ahead and try this! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Your method actually doesn't work as I expected. This seems to run the jobs serially one after another, and the total time of running 10 jobs is exactly the total time of running 1 job 10 times, but that SLURM approach gave a speedup. Are there any methods on SGE that could run these 10 jobs in parallel separate with each other? Thanks.

Comment: @KhunWasut Interesting, perhaps there is a limit set on the number of tasks (array jobs) that can run concurrently.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. Similar to what vince does below, I wrap 10 qsub commands in a normal bash script in the login node, and each of the job runs independently given that the # of processor I need is much less than what is available, which is almost always the case in my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri Chubarov's answer is excellent, and the most robust way to proceed as it places less load on the submit node when submitting many jobs (>1000). Alternatively, you can wrap `qsub` in a for loop:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "/path/to/exec /path/to/input${i}" | qsub
done
```

I sometimes use the above when whatever varies as input is not easily captured as a range of integers.

Example:

```
for f in `ls /some/path/input*`
do
    echo "/path/to/exec ${f}" | qsub
done
```

Comment: The first time I tried to do this on Grid Engine wasn't that great, because I assumed that the scheduler would assign the same # of processors per node and then I put a for loop that looks like the following in a single qsub script.

`while read line
do
    extract hostname from the line
    ssh hostname /path/to/exec /path/to/inputs
done < $PE_HOSTFILE`

But this doesn't always work though because the scheduler may assign different # of processors for each node. I will also try this as an alternative. Thank you!

Comment: In general, SGE takes care of selecting the node based on balancing out load on cluster.  But you can select specific nodes if you must using the `-l h=<node>` option. The number of processors that are reserved is dictated by the queue configuration and parameters to qsub (if parallel environment (PE) is enabled use -pe <PE> <processors desired>). With no PE, jobs are "reserved" one processor, but if the program uses more that is allowed, but system may be over loaded as SGE will not be aware of this.