# Setting SGE for running an executable with different input files on different nodes (updated: with some problems)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sungridengine, slurm

I know I asked the same question earlier from this link:

[Setting SGE for running an executable with different input files on different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200302/setting-sge-for-running-an-executable-with-different-input-files-on-different-no)

Like I said in that thread, I worked with this kind of thing on SLURM system before without any issues, because everything is wrapped into one submission script. However, adapting from the previous question in the link above, here is my approach on SGE (I know this is a bad practice, but I really couldn't think of any better ways...)

The job is chained through 4+N scripts: `run.sh`, `submitSerial.sh`, `wrap.sh`, `temp.sh`, and `job{1-N}.sh`

> `run.sh`: The main job script

```
#!/bin/bash

...some stuffs...
...create N directories to run N input files in parallel (like last problems)
...generate wrap.sh and job{1-N}.sh...

...parameters definition...

for (( i=0; i<=M; i++ ))
do
   ...generate submitSerial.sh...
   sh submitSerial.sh
   ...initialize boolean flag...
   while flag
   do
      sh wrap.sh
      ...run an executable to determine the flag status...
   done
done

...some cleanup...
```

> `submitSerial.sh` and `temp.sh`: I need to execute this executable in serial first,
>   and want the cluster to wait until this is done to proceed to the next
>   line of procedures in `run.sh`. Since `run.sh` is not in the cluster
>   environment (i.e. no Grid Engine parameters), but rather exists only
>   in a login node, this will generate `temp.sh` and run a serial script
>   through qsub right away. Since I don't know how to check whether a
>   qsub job is done, so I had to do it the foolish way. Wonder if there's
>   a better way to check?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "#!/bin/bash" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -N serialForce" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -q batch.q" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -l h_rt=0:10:00" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -pe orte 120" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -wd /path/to/working/dir/" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -j y" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -S /bin/bash" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "#$ -V" >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo >> $workDir/temp.sh
echo "mpirun -np 120 nwchem-6.5 $workDir/step0_1.nw" >> $workDir/temp.sh

qsub $workDir/temp.sh

while true
do
   qstat > $workDir/temp
   if [ -s $workDir/temp ]
   then
      sleep 1
   else
      rm $workDir/temp
      break
   fi
done

rm $workDir/temp.sh
```

> `wrap.sh` and `job{1-N}.sh`: This was generated earlier at the beginning
>   of the script. This is the part that was my question last time, and I
>   also used sleep to check the qsub status as well

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
   qsub $workDir/wd$i/job$i.sh
done

while true
do
   qstat > $workDir/temp
   if [ -s $workDir/temp ]
   then
      sleep 1
   else
      rm $workDir/temp
      break
   fi
done

for j in {1..10}
do
   rm $workDir/wd$j/*
done
```

The problem with this approach is once I run `run.sh`, I can't do it in the background and with having to do separate `qsub`'s there is a potential problem if the cluster is full. I wonder if there is a solution with only one `qsub` like the SLURM approach? I just want to submit the job and just wait until it's done rather than having the script submitting multiple qsub jobs without knowing if any unknown jobs die in the middle (and I never have an idea where it dies).

Please help me with this! Your help is highly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific and clear on what you are having issue with. I would appear that the last question you refer to largely address the `wrap.sh` and `jobN.sh` scripts i.e. use job arrays.

To address your other concern ie, how to check/wait for job to complete, see below.

To have job wait for another job to complete use the `qsub` option `-hold_jid`. To apply this to multiple jobs, each dependant on previous one to complete, my first thought would be a for loop. E.g.:

```
holdid=$(echo "<some code for job 1>" | qsub -terse)
for jobn in {1..99}
do
   holdid=$(echo "<some code for jobn>" | qsub -terse -hold_jid ${holdid})
done
```

I am happy to edit this reply to help you out further.

Comment: Hi Vince, Actually I've also explored some other possibilities and also started a new thread. My issues might be able to be resolved by using the application context feature of mpirun, but I still had some problems with it, which is described in this new thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481433/mpirun-app-option-on-grid-engine-for-mpmd-settings

I also looked at the SGE array job as a possible solution, but I state some concerns in that thread as well. Could you maybe please have a look on that thread too? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I actually look into the `-hold_jid` option for `qsub` as well. It potentially solves my problem, but I still have a concern that a job I'm running may take a course of several hours or up to a day, and the cluster I'm working on isn't too reliable and some `qsub` jobs may get stuck. At least when I worked with SLURM everything is wrapped into one submission, but it looks like I have to do multiple (probably thousands) of submission to do the same problem.

Comment: Another concern is when I submit a job into my cluster, sometimes it gets stuck at `qw` for ages and won't run (don't know what's the reason). If everything is in one submission, if this happens I can just delete the job right away and start a new one. However, if this thing happens when I'm at, say, the 543th job, it would be really frustrating that the job got stuck in the automated script without being able to track it, and time would be wasted doing it over again without being able to intercept the problem at first. Do you have any solutions that help wrapping everything into one script?